# Javascript Code does nothing when executed

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to build an incremental game, but NONe of my javascript code is working, whether I access it locally or upload it to a webhost.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<script src="game.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <h1>Incremental!</h1>

<button id="click" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">CLICK ME</button>
<hr>
<p>Clicks: <span id="total_clicks">0</span>
</p>
<p>Auto Clicks Per Second: <span id="autoClickers">0</span>
</p>
<hr>
<button id="autoClickerBuy" class="btn btn-info btn-block">BUY AN AUTOCLICKER</button>
<!--ADDED--><button id="upgradeTwoClicks" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">TWO CLICKS PER CLICK</button>
<!--ADDED--><button id="upgradeTwoAutoClicks" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">TWO CLICKS PER AUTOCLICKER</button></div>
```

And the Javascript file(game.js) is as follows:

```
var totalClicks = 0;

$('#click').click(function(){
totalClicks++;
document.getElementById("total_clicks").innerHTML = totalClicks;
});
```

I cannot figure out why it isn't working...it's literally a copy and paste from a tutorial.

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: If you are using JQuery, `document.getElementById("total_clicks").innerHTML` can be replaced with `$("#total_clicks").html...`

Comment: have you checked your browser console? it is an invaluable tool when testing javascript.

Comment: My console outputs "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.html:4
(anonymous function)" on load, and nothing when I click the button.

Comment: you haven't include your jquery plugin properly, please include it and need to be in order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scripts that appear initial in the HTML are executed sequentially, *in order*.

The `$` function, from jQuery, is not found because the game code (game.js) is run *before* jQuery library has been loaded. Change the order such that:

```
<!-- dependencies first -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- dependents -->
<script src="game.js"></script>
```

---

Scripts can also be loaded "async", but such is not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

open develop tool of your browser(firebug in firefox, for example) and watch console errors...
But reading your code... have you include jquery library?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is included now with: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

i have create a jsfiddle using your code and its working fine for me see the link of jsfiddle.

i think you have not included jQuery file in your html page.

code:-

```
var totalClicks = 0;

$('#click').click(function(){
totalClicks++;
document.getElementById("total_clicks").innerHTML = totalClicks;
});
```

link-
http://jsfiddle.net/XUjAH/1092/

thanks

Comment: 'My console outputs "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.html:4 (anonymous function)" '

Comment: this means you have included jquery at top in your page

Answer (score 0):

Try this link: http://jsfiddle.net/VDV6L/  you missed this
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`